# IOS 7 Singleton Problems

Tags: objective-c, ios7, singleton

Hi I know this isn't a new question, but I read a lot here and nothing helped me to find the Problem.

I have a singleton Class UserFunctions

```
@interface UserFunctions : NSObject {

    NSUserDefaults *NSUser;

/* 
    NSString *name;
    NSString *email;
   */
}


+ (UserFunctions *)sharedInstance ;

@property (nonatomic,assign) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSString *email;
```

On the m class:

```
@synthesize name;
@synthesize email;


+ (UserFunctions *)sharedInstance
{

    static UserFunctions *sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[UserFunctions alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;


}


-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSUser = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        self = [NSUser objectForKey:@"UserFunctions"];
        self.name=@"Test";
    }
    return self;
}
```

On Another Class i try to Save

```
UserFunction = [UserFunctions sharedInstance]; UserFunction.name = userjson.username; UserFunction.email = userjson.email;
```

and if i directly try to read:

```
NSString *test = [UserFunction email];
```

i get nil in the String.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Why do you make a singleton instead of just functions outside of a class? Not creating a singleton is the best way to avoid singleton-related issues.

Comment: @rightfold are you really from North Korea?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Of course not. If I lived there I’d be killed if I got access to this website.

Comment: @rightfold i dont understand your first issue. I need a singleton class to share same user information and to have some functions to the values.

Comment: Except you're wrong. You can do all those things without singletons. Did you mean you "need" global variables? Because, you know, baaaaad.

Comment: Do u mean it is better to make global variables and not to use singleton? i thought this would be the best way.

Comment: @MichaelBoiman No, I mean that Singletons combine the badness of global variables (Action At A Distance, tight coupling) with the annoyance of unnecessary restrictions (e.g. hindering testability, hindering composition for threaded systems, solliciting initialization order fiascos or uncontrollable application shutdown etc)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use an `assign` property for objects (unless you "retain" that object elsewhere)

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSString *email;
```

should be : (if you're using ARC)

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *email;
```

On a sidenote, one thing that disturbed me while reading your code : you should definitely not have an iVar called `NSUser` it looks an awful lot like a class name and it gets in the way when reading your code :)

Comment: thanks, i try it how you said and change the VariableName (you're right)!

Comment: Weird : Are you sure that `userjson` has data ? :)

Comment: I found the error, i tried to save the object in nsuserdefault and to load in init
self = [NSUser objectForKey:@"UserFunctions"];
But maybe it broke something. Now I need only to find a way to store the information in NSUSERDEFAULT without to put every single variable in it. Thanks for your help.